# pymssql: Install/import without issues, but DB doesn't return results

Tags: python-2.7, freetds, pymssql

I believe I've installed all of the dependencies correctly, but when I try to query the DB, the cursor returns zero results always.

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='some_host', user='blah', password='blah', database='some_db')
>>> crsr = conn.cursor()
>>> crsr.execute('SELECT TOP 10 * from d_user')
>>> print crsr.fetchall()
[]
```

I know the query executed correctly against the DB, because I can see the query results in the freetds log files.

What's going on here?

Setup: python 2.7.5, current version of pymssql (pip installed), brew install freetds, Mac OSX 10.8.3.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? I recently had this start occurring as well, when it worked previously.

Comment: We're running 2008 R2